# Create a copy of an existing record into a new row and update a few value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with a table that keeps tracks with all changes so if there is a change, the old record of the client is end dated and a new record is created with a copy of the new values.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Create a copy of the old record into a new record but increment the primary key
2. Make updates to the new record
3. End date the old record

My main challenge is how do I

- Create a copy of the old record
- **And** create a new key
- Without having to list all the columns manually

I can create a copy of the record no problem.

```sql
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE WHERE ID=XX
```

However the table has a primary key so I can't exactly just make a copy.
Also, since I want to update the copied record, I want to store the key as well.

I could write the below code, but there are a lots of columns.

```sql
INSERT SCHEMA.TABLE (Col1, Col2)
VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR SCHEMA.COL1,VAL2)
```

And lastly I want to add my update my record so I need to capture the value of the new key.
This isn't a problem as long as I have the new key.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the `OUTPUT` clause to obtain the new id and use it to update the new record. As for "I could write the below code, but there are a lots of columns." - thats life I'm afraid.

Comment: if the primary key is `IDENTITY` then you can insert then do `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` which will return the new key.